# Use customized framework library(android.jar) within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I had my own customized framework(android.jar) and want to use it within Android Studio. I had description in my build.gradle like:

```
dependencies {
     compile files('myandroid.jar')
}
```

But Android Studio still use the default framework(android.jar). Expected situation is like Eclipse, I can arrange the order of libraries. In Android Studio, I can only arrange external libraries' order and have nothing to do with the default framework library. Is there a way to let my customized android.jar had higher order than the default one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This issue is not about my module can't reference my customized android.jar. It seems caused by both my customized framework library and the default framework library(Android SDK's library) have same classes, for example:android.telephony.ServiceState. And Android studio just uses the default framework library(Android SDK's library) that my new added APIs for android.telephony.ServiceState become unrecognized...

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: No, I still not get the answer! However, you can try to combine the default android.jar with your customized one. Unzip both .jar, copy the missing classes from original android.jar, zip back to .jar.... You can write a simple program to let this work easier....

Comment: Did you get the answer now?

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767723/4740738, it works for me.

Comment: This answer may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512503/11928256

Answer (score 4):

Place this line inside your dependencies:

```
provided files('libs/myandroid.jar')
```

If still not work, so we can add our library to build classpath. In application's build.gradle, add these:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:app\\libs\\mylibs.jar')
        }
    }
}
```

I placed mylib.jar is in app/libs. There maybe some errors display on IDE, but application's build will be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it seems that you can put your library in other folder as long as the file path is correct. And it is the libraries's reference ORDER bothering me... I want my customized classes replace the one that Android framework already exists. In that case I must ensure my customized framework.jar had higher reference priority!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is adding your `.jar` in your `libs` folder, then right clic on it and select `add as a library`.

Then if it doesnt work already, try to right clic on your project folder and select `Open Modules settings`. You can manage your dependency and your libraries there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But in Android Studio, I can't let my android.jar had higher priority than the default one. Even I open the "Modules Settings" window, the default android.jar is not in the list, and I can't still guarantee my customized android.jar would be referenced first....

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,In your modules's build.gradle file .

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/myandroid.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it seems that you can put your library in other folder as long as the file path is correct. And it is the libraries's reference order bothering me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
       tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
           options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:/mylib.jar')
       }
    }
}
```

http://www.jianshu.com/p/a25a85b6372d
[How to put my libraries in front of android.jar by editing build.gradle in Android-Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441398/how-to-put-my-libraries-in-front-of-android-jar-by-editing-build-gradle-in-andro)