# Use a custom android.jar in an Android Studio project to compile against

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

A standard Android project uses the *sdk.dir* property in your *local.properties* to find your local Android SDK and resolve the appropriate *android.jar* file to use for compiling against for all of the platform classes.

I'm working on an Android system app so I know I will have access to certain classes an methods that are not ordinarily accessible to standard apps.

I still want to work in Android Studio though so I work with a modified android.jar which I use to overwrite the standard one in my SDK folder.

This approach works fine but I want to know if there is a way to achieve this without butchering my local SDK jar files.

In short, how can I get gradle to resolve an android.jar file of my choosing for compilation purposes but still use the SDK folder for everything else?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381754/use-customized-framework-libraryandroid-jar-within-android-studio)