# Use custom android.bluetooth. instead of one present in default sdk android.jar in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, jar

I wanted to use custom android.bluetooth instead of which presend in android.jar which comes with android SDK. I compiled android.bluetooth into seperate jar file and imported into studio apk project. After making it as a module, Studio is able to resolve my custom APIs added in BluetoothAdapter.java. 
But while compiling i am getting method not found error, as "cannot find symbol method xxx"

I tried steps mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441398/how-to-put-my-libraries-in-front-of-android-jar-by-editing-build-gradle-in-andro/41767723#41767723), to edit gradle files to change the order and adding Xbootpath. But still fails. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can't just replace android api class. It compiles against your class but when you try to run it it first loads the android class which doesn't have the methods you added.

Comment: So how do we add custom APIs and test ?

Answer (score 2):

The `bootclasspath` parameter must be an absolute path. So, you should modify build.gradle like this:

```
def androidJar = file('android.jar') // obtain you jar file
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs.add("-Xbootclasspath/p:$androidJar") // file.toString() is absolute path.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. And one tip for you, make sure *-Xbootclasspath/p:$androidJar* was inside double quote.